# Python quit unexpectedly when running Python programs from terminal

Tags: terminal, homebrew, python, macos

I am using Terminal to run code on my macOS High Sierra. I use Python all the time on my laptop (all day every day) and this is the first time I have seen this and it's come somewhat suddenly. I haven't used any new libraries that I don't usually use.

**The Error**

The error is a pop-up when I run code after importing it from another file that says:

`Python has quite unexpectedly
Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.`

**Attempts to Fix**

I've tried uninstalling a re-installing Python (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40732280/python-quit-unexpectedly-on-mac) using the following commands:

`brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force python python@2
unset PYTHONPATH
brew install python python@2`

and

`brew uninstall --ignore-dependencies --force python python@3
unset PYTHONPATH
brew install python python@3`

This doesn't help. I've also quit all processes and restarted them. This also doesn't work.

The only thing I can think of that I've done today that I've never done before is create the ability to open a .xps file in my Google drive.

**Where the Error is Coming From**

I have a long class called `preprocess_in_batches.PreprocessForTopicModelling` which has an attribute called `preprocess`. If I do the following in `preprocess_in_batches.py` it works fine:

`if __name__ == "__main__":
    preprocess = PreprocessForTopicModelling(gpu=False)
    preprocess.preprocess(...)`

However, if I do it from another Python file, then I get this weird quitting of Python:

`from preprocess_in_batches import PreprocessForTopicModelling
def test_preprocess_in_batches():
    preprocess = PreprocessForTopicModelling(gpu=False)
    preprocess.preprocess(...)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    test_preprocess_in_batches()`

I just don't understand why Python is quitting. Firstly I can't see anything illegal that I'm doing with my code. And even if there is a simple bug I'm missing, why is it quitting instead of throwing up an error?

Comment: Since you have both python2 and python3 on your machine are you using virtual environments?

Comment: How are you running python as that looks like a gui crash.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have exactly the same issue